# I have problem while uploading the csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

The csv file will insert new values if the details for the particular month is not already present and it will update the rows with the new datas in the table if the  details of the particular month is already present in the table by uploading the csv file.

The last row of the csv file is getting repeated all over the column in the table payslip. I know there is some mistake in my query or something. But i couldnt figure out what is wrong. can anyone please help me solve this issue ?

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';

if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
$fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$chk_file = explode(".",$fname);

if(strtolower($chk_file[1]) == 'csv')
{
//$sel=mysql_query("select * from employee where month='$month'");
//$del=mysql_query("delete from employee where month='$month'");
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payslips where month='$month'");
$pay_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query1);
    $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
    fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");
    if($pay_num_rows > 1)
    {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != false)
    {
    $upd = "UPDATE payslips SET    month='$data[9]',tot_work_days='$data[10]',lop_days='$data[11]',arrear_amt='$data[12]',leave_encash='$data[13]' where month='$month'";
    mysql_query($upd) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "Successfully Imported";
}
  if($pay_num_rows == 0)
{
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != false)
    {
    $sql = "INSERT into   payslips(employee_code,employee_name,employee_address,emp_dateofjoin,emp_designation,emp_hq,pf_num,esic_num,emp_state,month,tot_work_days,lop_days,arrear_amt,leave_encash) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$month','$data[10]','$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13]')";

    //$upd = "UPDATE employee SET  month='$data[9]',tot_work_days='$data[10]',lop_days='$data[11]',arrear_amt='$data[12]',leave_encash='$data[13]' where month='$month'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "Successfully Imported";

}
else
 {
    echo "Invalid File";
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: The data entered in the last row of the csv file is getting repeated to its upper rows. This is the exact bug i found in the above code. Can anyone please help me in figuring out in what am wrong ?

Comment: I am not getting ur point .. Did u mean that the last record in csv file is copied several times in db ?

Answer (score 0):

You can better use [PrseCSV](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/)  for getting data from the uploaded csv file.

Comment: Yeah i could have used but now its too late. I just need to fix that bug to make the application work fine for now. So i just need someone to help me finding that bug out.