# Please help, bug while uploading a csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have problem while uploading the csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936751/i-have-problem-while-uploading-the-csv-file)

The csv file will insert new values if the details for the particular month is not already present and it will update the rows with the new datas in the table if the details of the particular month is already present in the table by uploading the csv file.

The last row of the csv file is getting repeated all over the column in the table payslip. I know there is some mistake in my query or something. But i couldnt figure out what is wrong. can anyone please help me solve this issue ?

```
 <?php
    require_once '../config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {
    $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $chk_file = explode(".",$fname);

    if(strtolower($chk_file[1]) == 'csv')
    {
    //$sel=mysql_query("select * from employee where month='$month'");
    //$del=mysql_query("delete from employee where month='$month'");
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payslips where month='$month'");
    $pay_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query1);
    $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
    fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");
    if($pay_num_rows > 1)
    {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != false)
    {
    $upd = "UPDATE payslips SET     month='$data[9]',tot_work_days='$data[10]',lop_days='$data[11]',arrear_amt='$data[12]',leav    e_encash='$data[13]' where month='$month'";
    mysql_query($upd) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "Successfully Imported";
    }
   if($pay_num_rows == 0)
    {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) != false)
    {
    $sql = "INSERT into    payslips(employee_code,employee_name,employee_address,emp_dateofjoin,emp_designation,emp_hq    ,pf_num,esic_num,emp_state,month,tot_work_days,lop_days,arrear_amt,leave_encash)  values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[    7]','$data[8]','$month','$data[10]','$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13]')";
    //$upd = "UPDATE employee SET          month='$data[9]',tot_work_days='$data[10]',lop_days='$data[11]',arrear_amt='$data[12]',leav    e_encash='$data[13]' where month='$month'";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "Successfully Imported";

     }
       else
      {
     echo "Invalid File";
     }
     }
     }

        ?>
```

Comment: Is the month inserted correctly? It looks as if $pay_num_rows might be 0 because it can't find any rows, therefor making more inserts instead. If you have empty rows in your csv these might create new rows, which aren't found as "months", since they don't have these values. You could try using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html instead.

Comment: You do know that MySQL has a csv-import feature build-in, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html, it does all the CSV loading for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are **a lot** of problems with the code you have posted, least of all the problem you are having. Firstly you are not escaping any variables, so [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) is a trivial exercise.

I also notice that when you check to see if the month exists in the database your `if` statement looks like this:

```
if($pay_num_rows > 1) ...
```

However this would indicate that you want to do an `UPDATE` if there is *more than one row*, but your problem describes it will do an `INSERT` if a *particular month is not already present*. I would start by fixing your conditional logic to be:

```
if($pay_num_rows >= 1){ 
    // UPDATE QUERY HERE
}
else {
    // INSERT QUERY HERE
}
```

The logic of updating if there is at least one row, or *a particular month is not already present* is now reflected in your structure.

Looking over your code again it appears your UPDATE loop will always update every record `WHERE month='$month'`, but `$month` is always the same for every loop, so when the query executes is matches every row it has already done. To be more clear, say your month is *January* and you have several rows in the database with the month equal to January it will update **ALL** those rows, therefore whatever the data in the last row is will be what is written to **every** row. You need to look into the `WHERE` clause of that query.